# SQL Azure rest api BeginExport... how to check if export completed

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to programmatically export an SQL Azure database to a BACPAC file and once the export has completed I need to delete the database.

The SQL Azure REST API allows me to submit an export request which will run and export the database to a blob storage container.

But... I can't see how to check on the status of the export request.

Here's the export api description: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases%20-%20Import%20Export/Export

And the overall SQL api description: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/

Answer (score 1):

The sys.dm_ operation_status DMV should help you know the status of the operation.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_ operation_status   
   WHERE major_resource_id = ‘myddb’   
   ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

For more inromation about this DMV, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-operation-status-azure-sql-database) documentation.

If you use PowerShell [New-Azure​RmSql​Database​Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabaseexport?view=azurermps-6.13.0) cmdlet you can use  [Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqldatabaseimportexportstatus?view=azurermps-6.13.0) cmdlet to track the progress of an export operation and of an import operation too.

Comment: Nope. The view does not include azure export tasks.

Comment: I need to do the same thing, except I need to check the status of an Import, not an export. Any luck on this?

Comment: @ColinLaws If you use PowerShell New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport  then you can use Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus to track the import operation.

Answer (score 0):

For any api such as BeginX(), there is a corresponding api X() which waits for completion. In this case, instead of [BeginExport()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.databasesoperationsextensions.beginexport?view=azure-dotnet) use [Export()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.databasesoperationsextensions.export?view=azure-dotnet).

If you wish to have more direct control over the polling, then you can [look inside the definition of Export and directly use the lower layer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/sqlmanagement/Microsoft.Azure.Management.SqlManagement/src/Generated/DatabasesOperations.cs):

```
        public async Task<AzureOperationResponse<ImportExportResponse>> ExportWithHttpMessagesAsync(string resourceGroupName, string serverName, string databaseName, ExportRequest parameters, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // Send request
            AzureOperationResponse<ImportExportResponse> _response = await BeginExportWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, parameters, customHeaders, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Poll for completion
            return await Client.GetPostOrDeleteOperationResultAsync(_response, customHeaders, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

This answer is specifically for .net but for other languages the same principle applies.